# recursive diff of files case-insensitive

Tags: bash, diff

How do I run a recursive diff when the filenames are the same but have different cases?

For instance:

```
./Root/Directory/FileName.txt
./Branch/directory/filename.txt
```

`diff -r -i Root Branch` only performs case insensitive on file contents not name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option `--ignore-file-name-case` is what you need:

```
diff -r --ignore-file-name-case Root Branch
```

e.g.

```
mkdir dir1 dir2
touch dir1/fred dir2/Fred

diff -r dir1 dir2
Only in dir1: fred
Only in dir2: Fred

diff -r --ignore-file-name-case dir1 dir2  # no output - files match
```